# Fastest way to to draw stroke/outline around text in SharpDX c#?

Tags: c#, sharpdx

I am able to draw stroke around the text in sharpDX but it is very slow.

Here is my code:

```
d2dRenderTarget.DrawTextLayout(new Vector2(298, 300), textLayout0, textBrush1,DrawTextOptions.NoSnap);

d2dRenderTarget.DrawTextLayout(new Vector2(302, 300), textLayout0, textBrush1, DrawTextOptions.NoSnap);

d2dRenderTarget.DrawTextLayout(new Vector2(300, 302), textLayout0, textBrush1, DrawTextOptions.NoSnap);

d2dRenderTarget.DrawTextLayout(new Vector2(300, 298), textLayout0, textBrush1, DrawTextOptions.NoSnap);

d2dRenderTarget.DrawTextLayout(new Vector2(300, 300), textLayout0, textBrush, DrawTextOptions.NoSnap);
```

Here is my output:

[image]

Is there anyother solution to draw same thing around text?

Answer (score 2):

**Distance Field Fonts** perhaps is what you are looking for. It is the fast and qualitative technique of rendering super-smooth scalable bitmap fonts.

- Take a look at it in this document; there you will find such text effects like outlining, glow, drop shadow: https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/valve/2007/SIGGRAPH2007_AlphaTestedMagnification.pdf
- libgdx implementation of **SDF** can be used as the reference. You can find it here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Distance-field-fonts

Implementation of **SDF** requires some knowledge of shaders programming. Hope my answer helps

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a quick run down and how I attacked it, this will most likely not fit at all with your current implementation.  But i found faster.

I'm using Codehead's bitmap font generator to use textures to render my custom renderder.  This is for DirectX 11 Direct3d.  I then renderer these as tiles onto the screen in screen space.  Normally, the shader would be a 1 to 1 pixel render, in this case though, you're wanting to edge your texture with a different colour.  This in itself is similar to an anti aliasing technique.  For this, I use a "Percentage Closer Filter" algorithm which basically samples 5 points, 1 pixel in each direction plus the centre.  if I get 1 black pixel returned in any direction then I have hit an edge and colour accordingly.  There are much better versions of this out here, but that's how I approached it.